# Trouble manually setting the model property using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple model, which is:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var citySchema   = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    state: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'State' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('City', citySchema);
```

Only i access a route, asking to insert a city, giving as post params

POST: {
  name: 'My City',
  state: 'SE' // Stands for Some State
}

I know the type of the state property is not correct, but in my logic i do:

```
var newCity = new City(req.body);

if (typeof req.body.state !== 'undefined' && req.body.state.length == 2) {
    State.findOne({uf: req.body.state.toUpperCase()}, function(err, foundState) {
        if (err) { res.send({status: 500, message: 'Could not find the required state'}); return; }
        newCity.state = foundState._id;
        newCity.set('state', foundState._id);
        return;
    });
}
```

But, once i do a res.send(newCity), to check out the newCity variable properties, it prints:

```
{
  "name": "Balneário Camború",
  "_id": "570ff2944c6bd6df4e8e76e8"
}
```

And if i try to save it, i get the following error:

```
ValidationError: CastError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"SE\" at path \"state\""
```

So, i'm quite confused, because when the Model is created using the req.body properties, it does not list the state property, even if i set it later in the code, but when i try to save the City, it throw an error of mistype.

What could be causing this, and how should i procede?

Comment: Why you call that: `newCity.set('state', foundState._id);`? And how do you save newCity?

Comment: I've read something about the (s,g)etters of models when using mongoose, so i figure i should try both whays, accessing the property directly, os using the setter. I save it using newCity.save(function(err) { /* Logic here */ });

Comment: When you save it? In `State.findOne` callback or outside of it?

Comment: Outside. Good point, if i do the res.send inside the callback of the State.find, i can see the state property of the city.

Comment: You **must** call `newCity.save()` in `State.findOne` callback, because `findOne` is async function, and `newCity.state` is initialized only when state is found. In your current implementation you save `newCity` before it's initialized with new state, because of that you're getting that error,